# File uploads in IE8 and IE9

Tags: php, internet-explorer, file-upload, upload, apc

This question may have been asked multiple times, but I haven't been able to find a proper answer.

I'm developing a website that also includes an image upload. Using HTML5 APIs I have been able to create individual progress bars for every image upload process.
As noted in the official documentation, IE9 and earlier versions don't support multiple file uploads and HTML5 APIs.

What I need is a progress bar for IE9 and lower. 
I've read that iframes aren't capable of displaying the progress of file uploads. Neither I want to resort to some flash upload plugin.

I've also read that it is possible to add APC support (if not present) to the server which is configured to report the file's upload progress.

So, how safe is APC and are there any other possible ways of displaying progress bar in IE9 and lower versions?

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, APC is considered 'deprecated' and  [Session Upload Progress](http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php) should be used instead!